# Should I create many to many relationship?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm stuck ATM. Months passed since I did the latest website development, and I'm feeling stupid now.

I've created in Doctrine2 a class named `User`, and one other class named `Publication`.

`Publication` class has a ManyToOne relationship with `User`, so I can identify which `User` created that `Publication`.

Like that:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;
```

Now, what I want to do, is create a Many To Many (**I guess**) relationship between those two classes to do the following:

- Every user can give `points` (int) to any publication.

In Mysql Schema, I think I should end up with a 3rd table called something like `User_Voted_Publication` however I'm not sure how to do that in Doctrine.

If I just create a ManyToMany relationship, I can't add the attribute `points` which will hold the number of how many points did any `User` give to any specific `Publication`.

Any tips are appreciated.

Thank you so much, and sorry if this question seems to be stupid. I already feel like that =).

Comment: Make yourself a UserVotedPublication entity with an attribute of points.  Then make one-to-many relations between it and your User/Publication entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience (anyone feel free to chime in if I am wrong), a many-to-many relationship in doctrine only allows for the use of the primary keys (in your case, the user_id and publication_id).  If there are any other fields in the table (the User_Voted_Publication table), doctrine won't recognize them.  What I have done to get around this is create the new entity (User_Voted_Publication), and then create a one-to-many relationship with both other tables (user and publication tables).

This will allow you to add any other field in the User_Voted_Publication table that you want.  One thing that I noticed that may not be ideal... I had to create an auto-increment id field in the table instead of using the natural primary key(user_id, publication_id), but it still works fine. I just made a unique constraint on the two fields(user_id, publication_id).